# How to deploy artifacts from Azure devops to Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am setting up CI CD jobs and publish/deploy artifacts from Azure Devops [VSTS] to Apache Tomcat, which is best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to deploy artifacts from Azure devops to Apache Tomcat?

You could use the extension [Apache Tomcat Deployment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.apachetomcat) to deploy WAR to Tomcat server.

1. Build pipeline that creates artifacts with the .war file.
2. Install the extension Apache Tomcat Deployment.
3. Deploy applications to a Tomcat server using the **Deploy to Apache Tomcat** task.

Reference below articles to do that:

- [Continuous Integration and Deployment of Java web apps to Azure with
  VSTS](https://cmatskas.com/continuous-integration-and-deployment-of-java-web-apps-to-azure-with-vsts/)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tomcat/blob/master/src/tomcat.md

Hope this helps.